# Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Event> has no method 'split'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm writing a Javascript function to preload pictures on a website.

```
function preload(images) {
if (document.images) {
        var i = 0;
        var imageArray = new Array();
        imageArray = images.split(';');
        var imageObj = new Image();
        for(i=0; i<=imageArray.length-1; i++) {
        imageObj.src=images[i];
        }
    }
}
preload('img1.jpg;img2.jpg;img3.jpg');
```

It's giving me an error: 
    Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'split'

What is causing this? How can i fix it?

Please let me know if I should provide more information,
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it now, images[i] will not give you name of image. You have image names in imageArray. I changed images[i] to imageArray[i]

```
function preload(images) {
if (document.images) {
        var i = 0;
        var imageArray = new Array();
        imageArray = images.split(';');
        var imageObj = new Image();
        for(i=0; i<=imageArray.length-1; i++) {
        imageObj.src=imageArray[i];
        }
    }
}
preload('img1.jpg;img2.jpg;img3.jpg');
```

Comment: Oops... Thanks a lot! I'll make sure to double check my code before posting next time!

Comment: You are welcome. I checked there was nothing wrong with your split. Any how if you think this answer solved your problem you may accept the answer to help other for correct answer.

Comment: As Adil mentioned, I changed images[i] to imageArray[i] and it worked! thanks a lot guys